# Why am I getting a thaumite's infestation?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

In one of my late runs something really weird happened: nearly half of the monsters I slayed became infested with thaumites as soon as they died. I was running a skill setup *without* Golemancy, so I was wondering where they could come from. The run ended quickly enough to not let me investigate further, and it never happened again afterwards.

Is there something that can make it happen or was it just a random and bizarre glitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more likely possibility is that [you got an enchantment of thaumites](http://community.gaslampgames.com/threads/it-infects-your-enemies-with-ravenous-thaumites.542/) in the weapon which then has a chance of causing a thaumite infestation on anything you hit.  See [Thaumite infection from the Anvil of Kong](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Anvil_of_Krong) for more specifics on the exact damage effects of this.

This enchantment is possible to intentionally put on a weapon with a hiveweapon crust.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trap which releases Thaumite Infestation when triggered. It appears on later levels in a dungeon, so I assume this is what infected the monsters you met.

Comment: It can be this, even if it seems weird that 6 monsters in a row triggered the same trap...

Answer (score 0):

Thaumite infection SPREADS. Only one schmuck has to start getting infected (either from an enchanted weapon or a trap) for it to spread to other monsters, and it can keep going after those monsters die.

Works wonders on zoos.

Comment: I know the mechanics of a thaumite infestation. The weird thing was that before death the monster was healthy (if you exclude the occasional stabbing from me), after he was infested. Only started to notice that after my 4th- 5th kill, and died shortly afterwards, but I strongly suspect, as MichaelT suggested, it was the result of a Kong's blessing.